# How to merge ID and Displayname from different objects? [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, merge

I'm trying to merge user id and username.

My current output only outputs the ID, which I'm trying to replace by display name, but the source is different. How do I best proceed?

Request:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All"
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Identity.Governance

# Read resource roles, split into individual strings
$ResourceRoles = Get-MgBetaEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignmentResourceRole <#-- -all --#> | Select-Object OriginId, OriginSystem, Status
$ResourceRoles_trim = $ResourceRoles.OriginId -split ',\s*' | ForEach-Object Trim
$ResourceRoles | Export-Csv 'C:\ResourceRolesBefore.csv' -NoTypeInformation
# Create 3 seperate objects
$OutputFile = $ResourceRoles_trim | ForEach-Object {
  # start by splitting the string into 3 after `_`
 $Type,$ResourceRole,$Target = $_ -split '_'
  # create the object
  [pscustomobject]@{
    "Role" = $Type
    "ResourceRole Objectid" = $ResourceRole
    "Target Objectid" = $Target
  }
}
# Export to CSV
$OutputFile | Export-Csv 'C:\ResourceRoles.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
Role               ResourceRole Objectid                Target Objectid
----               ---------------------                ---------------
Member             1ab9a07c-7g03-4bnc-9634-97c84ce3vb7i 1a521e7b-4f9e-3c03-ad42-a0ffbjb78686
Member             1ab9a07c-7g03-4bnc-9634-97c84ce3vb7i 0gfc76d8-e5ad-22d9-a48e-5ba8b3386479
...
```

Goal is to check and Merge against this Requst:
`$Userreport = Get-MgUser | Select-Object Id, DisplayName`

Output:

```
Id                                   DisplayName
--                                   -----------
e73978ed-b743-464e-b738-7338078cd503 Hans, Eimer
```

I hope it is understandable and described in detail.

Thanks and regards

Comment: There's lots of similar questions if you search for "Powershell join csv" - If you adapt the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63388914/3156906 you can use something like ```$roles | foreach-object { $r = $_; $_ | Add-Member "DisplayName" ($users | where-object { $_.Id -eq $r."Target Objectid" }).DisplayName; }```, assuming your two datasets are called ```$roles``` and ```$users```.

Comment: This one is solved, Ty @mclayton